# Scroll Bar On Overflow: Auto Doesn't Show On IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Good day, Everyone!

Yet another designing issue with IE, I have a working OVERFLOW:AUTO DIV on my web page that is perfectly working on Chrome, however - the scroll bar (or basically, the overflow syntax doesn't work) is not showing on IE, and the DIV is showing all the images inside the DIV.

I'm currently using this code block:

```
<DIV STYLE="WIDTH=50%; HEIGHT: 100%; OVERFLOW: AUTO;">
     Bunch of elements here.
</DIV>
```

It would be noteworthy that I'm using this OVERFLOWING DIV vertically, if that helps. Any ideas?

IE Version: 11.

Comment: have you tried setting overflow-x and overflow-y separately? Also, which version of Internet Explorer are you using? Is it running in quirks mode? Have you included an X-UA-Compatibility Meta Tag?

Answer (score -2):

height:100% not working without position relative, absolute you can use px and you write wrong style`STYLE="WIDTH=50%;` write `width:50%;` like:https://jsfiddle.net/phhc7ckf/

it's working  https://jsfiddle.net/phhc7ckf/

Answer (score -2):

if you are trying to make custom scrollbar than you can use jquery.nicescroll for making crossbrowser scroll bars , here is the link https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll

Comment: Try to give a complete answer. Make a running snippet or jsfiddle so that the OP can see the result

Comment: sure from next time i will try the same as you suggest thanks for guidance